# Выборка категорий и подкатегорий в MySQL

Tags: база-данных, select, mysql

Скажем, есть таблица `Category`.
в ней поля - `ID_main`, `ID_parent`, `Name`.

Категории верхнего уровня имеют `ID_parent = 1`,
категории ниже, `ID_parent` от `ID_main` своего родителя...

Тут я думаю, все ясно и так много где...

Но вот вопрос: я понимаю, что можно, сначала выбрать все категории с условием `WHERE ID_parent = 1`. И уже внутри этой выборки сделать еще один запрос, и т.д. если предполагать, что у нас может быть до 5 вложений, скажем, то 5 запросов каждый внутри другого...

Но можно ли сделать 1 Select к БД с такими условиями, чтобы все выбралось как мне надо?

Comment: Сформулируйте, как надо получить список в итоге? Как дерево?

Comment: @sergiks, интернет демократичен. Не стоит обижаться на обращение "ты". Это не в коем случае не отражает степень уважения к собеседнику. По крайней мере, с моей стороны. Мы тут все, фактически, без пола и возраста.

Впрочем, если напрягает, дальше буду на "вы".

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.id
from `table` t where t.ID_parent = 1
union all
select t2.id 
from `table` t 
join `table` t2 on t2.ID_parent = t.id
where t.ID_parent = 1
union all
select t3.id 
from `table` t 
join `table` t2 on t2.ID_parent = t.id
join `table` t3 on t3.ID_parent = t2.id
where t.ID_parent = 1
union all
select t4.id 
from `table` t 
join `table` t2 on t2.ID_parent = t.id
join `table` t3 on t3.ID_parent = t2.id
join `table` t4 on t4.ID_parent = t3.id
where t.ID_parent = 1
...
```

Думаю, идея понятна...

Есть еще вариант когда вложенность неограниченная, тогда делают строковое поле со значениями родителей типа `",1,2,123,4123,"` дальше сравнивают `like "%,"+ID_parent+",%"` но это для случая когда изменений структуры дерева не бывает (ну или дерево только растет, без переноса ветвей) да и со скоростью тут не совсем все просто.